# Multiplication of time dependent matrices.

Tags: matrices

I have a $\mathit{T\times P}$ matrix $\mathbf{B}$ and a $\mathit{P\times C}$ matrix $\mathbf{F}$. 
They can be quite large: $T=8760$, $C\approx20000$ and $P\approx 2000$.

In my code I perform the matrix multiplication $\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{F}$ using *BLAS* with the `macos` framework [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/blas) for performance.

Now I have a new use case. The matrix $\mathbf{F}$ needs to be time dependent. With this I mean that some of the elements in $\mathbf{F}$ are a function of time. Specifically I have $T=8760$ different matrices. Let us call these matrices $\mathbf{F}(t)$. Note that $t$ is the same row index of the matrix $\mathbf{B}$

The operation that I need to perform for this new use case is a loop. Specifically the vector-matrix multiplication between each row $t$ of $\mathbf{B}$ and the corresponding matrix $\mathbf{F}(t)$.
$$B_{t*}\mathbf{F}(t)$$

To finally obtain the $\mathit{T\times C}$ matrix $\mathbf{I}$.

The naive approach would require 8760 vector-matrix multiplications. Is there any way I can rearrange the matrices so that I can perform a limited number of operations (with larger matrices of course) that are supported by *BLAS*.

I am not a mathematician, so I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Are you performing $B \times F$ or $F \times B$? The dimensions don't seem to be appropriate for $B \times F$.

Comment: Ops. Fixed. I am performing $B\times F$